# excel disable auto update cell formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet that has a Changelog tab.  On every other tab I have a cell that references `=(Changelog!A1)` to display the latest version.  The changelog is listed in chronological order, newest first.  The problem is that when I add a new row, all the referencing cells update.

Here is an example of the changelog:

```
v1.0.2  | 1/4/2016  | Added Changelog tab
v1.0.1  | 1/4/2016  | Fixed some status cells that were not dropdowns
```

So currently all my tabs say `v1.0.2` but as soon as I insert a new row they switch to `=(Changelog!A2)` and *still* say `v1.0.2`

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: I think you'll need to use a Table

Comment: how do I reference the first cell of the first column in a table `tblChangeLog`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A formula like:

```
=ChangeLog!A1
```

will update when rows/columns are inserted/deleted in *ChangeLog*, but:

```
=INDIRECT("ChangeLog!A1")
```

will always give you top, left-most cell.